# Linq to sql left outer join

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Teikoku_Sections.Section_ID, Teikoku_Sections.Section_Name, Teikoku_Sections.Section_Code, Teikoku_Sections.Show_In_Menu FROM Teikoku_Sections WHERE Teikoku_Sections.Show_In_Menu = 1) AS Sections
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Teikoku_Divisions.Division_ID, Teikoku_Divisions.Division_Name, Teikoku_Divisions.Division_Code, Teikoku_Divisions.Section_ID, Teikoku_Divisions.Show_In_Menu FROM Teikoku_Divisions WHERE Teikoku_Divisions.Show_In_Menu = 1) AS Divisions
ON Sections.Section_ID = Divisions.Section_ID;
```

Which performs a left outer join on the two tables Teikoku_Sections and Teikoku_Divisions and join the visible items from both tables together.

The tables have the structure:

Teikoku_Section:
Section_ID int,
Section_Name nvarchar(50),
Section_Code int,
Show_In_Menu bit

Teikoku_Divisions:
Division_ID int,
Division_Name nvarchar(50)
Division_Code int,
Section_ID int,    <== The ID of the parent section
Show_In_Menu bit

I would like to end up with a table showing all sections and divisions which have Show_In_Menu true, but in some cases there might not be any divisions corresponding to a section, hence the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

I just can't get my head round to how to do this in linq to sql.

So far I have:

```
//Get All Visible sections
    IQueryable<Teikoku_Section> visibleSections = from section in db.Teikoku_Sections where section.Show_In_Menu select section;
    //Get all visible divisions
    IQueryable<Teikoku_Division> visibleDivisions = from division in db.Teikoku_Divisions where division.Show_In_Menu select division;
    //Join the two together
    IQueryable menuItems = visibleSections.GroupJoin(visibleDivisions, section => section.Section_ID,
        division => division.Section_ID, (section, divisions) => new
        {
            Section_ID = section.Section_ID,
            Section_Name = section.Section_Name,
            Division_ID = divisions.Select(d => d.Division_ID),
            Division_Name = divisions.Select(d => d.Division_Name),
        });

    return menuItems;
```

Which doesn't quite work... I think I might be missing a SelectMany(), but I just can't figure where or how to put it.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Done, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into DefaultIfEmpty (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see how that helps... I only started using linq to sql last week and am still baffled by most of it.

Comment: There's an example in the 101 samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647#leftouterjoin. In your case if your just learning, I would recommend using the LINQ syntax over Lambda syntax. IQueryable menuItems = from section in visibleSections join joindivision in visibleDivisions on section.SectionID equals joindivision.SectionID into joined from division in joined.DefaultIfEmpty() select new        { section.Section_ID, section.Section_Name, division.Division_ID, division.Division_Name)    }); (Of course, you could grab a copy of LINQ in Action and check chapter 6 as well)

Comment: Thanks your two comments put me on the right track and I solved it. In linq syntax as you said. I'm posting my query for future reference, but marking this as answer since I wouldn't have got it otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this in linq syntax as recommended by Jim Wooley. I got the query working with the following syntax:

```
IQueryable<Teikoku_Section> visibleSections = from section in db.Teikoku_Sections
                                                  where section.Show_In_Menu
                                                  select section;

    IQueryable<Teikoku_Division> visibleDivisions = from division in db.Teikoku_Divisions
                                                    where division.Show_In_Menu
                                                    select division;

    IQueryable menuItems = from section in visibleSections
                join division in visibleDivisions on section.Section_ID equals division.Section_ID into joined_SectionDivision
                from menuItem in joined_SectionDivision.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    Section_ID = section.Section_ID,
                    Section_Name = section.Section_Name,
                    Division_ID = (menuItem == null) ? null : (int?)menuItem.Division_ID,
                    Division_Name = menuItem.Division_Name ?? null
                };
```

It took me hours to finally get to this result, so here are a couple of explanations for anybody who might be in the same situation.

I don't want a simple left outer join, but a join with conditions on the items of both tables, i.e. Show_In_Menu being true for items in both tables, but not necessarily simultaneously, so a section can be visible, but it's divisions might not, in which case I want only the section in the results without any divisions to appear once in the results.

For that reason I am creating two temp tables with just the visible section and division items and then performing the left outer join using these two sets of results.

One thing that got me puzzled for a while was the .DefaultIfEmpty() part, which is needed to deal with null joined items. Hope this helps somebody who is trying to do a left outer join someday.